# c# - Forcing a Window to open in full screen

Tags: c#, fullscreen

Short version:
New to writing code. 
Need to have every window that is restored or opened to go full screen. 
What functions do this?  Don't need it fully coded out just the functions and syntax.

Long version for those that want more information:
Ok this is my first post so small bit of background.  I am new to coding.  The last time I was in a coding class they were showing me Visual Basic 6, and it was new.  When I was taking that class I never thought I would need to use it.  Now I find myself in a place were I need to learn, so I am learning by doing.  I have been using code pieces people post up; then modifying them to do what I want and then deconstructing them to make them work.  Because of that I have found out how to make a simple register application for me to use at an art table I setup every few months, and even force the numlock to stay on even if someone turns it off.

I now have a new problem, and this is where I need the help.  I need to create a program that runs in the background that will force all windows that are opened after it starts up and all windows that are restored from the task bar to open in full screen.

I have found a power shell script that was posted up to cause all windows to restore in a previous state and I got it to restore to full screen.

I need to know how can I see what application was just opened and then have it force it to open as full.

If you can point me to example of the various pieces I can slap them together and modify them to work for what I need.

I am working in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

Hope this is better for you than the first post.

Comment: We dont really need your bio or CV to answer a programming question (which you failed to ask).  Thats likely to get you some DVs

Comment: Wanted to let you know you were working with a new coder, someone you may need to explain things a bit more than normal.  And the question is simply what c# functions with syntax would I need to do that function I am looking for.  In this case looking at all window that are in the task bar and when they are restored to auto full screen them no mater the previous state and how to get it to read new windows opened and do the same thing?  If you can point me to what they are I can hash it out from there

Comment: As a new coder we are giving you advice on how to interact with other developers on stack overflow. I recommend reading ["How to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) at least once since you are new to coding.

Comment: Trust me, *everything* we need to know about your level of expertise is amply displayed in the lingo used and in the code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Thank you Chris.  I will look it over

Comment: Than you Chis, your post was helpful.  I guess the question I truly have is given the results I want, where do I start to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this functionality isn't directly exposed in the .net libraries. You'll have to use these 3 (at least) pinvoke functions: [EnumDesktopWindows](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumdesktopwindows), [IsWindowVisible](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.iswindowvisible), and [ShowWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.showwindow). You need the `IsWindowVisible` function because there are lots of Windows API hwnds that aren't what you normally think of as windows.

Comment: Thank you.  It gives me a place to start looking, I can work it from there.  You are the best.